To make 'trim' and 'atrim' work synchronously
The following command trims a video using the trim video filter:
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf "trim='00\:00\:05':'00\:00\:10',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" output.mp4

But if the video also contains audio stream, it will not be trimmed.
I tried
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf "trim='00\:00\:05':'00\:00\:10',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -af "atrim='00\:00\:05':'00\:00\:10'" output.mp4

ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -filter "trim='00\:00\:05':'00\:00\:10',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" output.mp4

but the 2nd version returns an error, and the 1st creates a "wrong" video. By "wrong" I mean that the output video is now somewhat consists of two parts, the 1st part is silent, and the 2nd does have a static image.
How to combine -vf trim and -af atrim so that they will work synchronously?

You may try -filter_complex with trim, atrim, setpts, asetpts and concat. Take a look at the following post. Note that for simple cases using -ss and -t is simpler (and sometime works without re-encoding).

@Rotem Thanks, I will try. Sorry for asking here, because it is not really related to the question, but could you explain whether there is any difference between ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:05 -to 00:00:10 output.mp4 and ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -to 00:00:10 -i input.mp4 output.mp4? At the first glance, both seem to work the same, but is it really so?

Better try without re-encoding: ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -to 00:00:10 -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4. For MP4 it is faster to use the -ss before the -i, because MP4 file stores a list of seeking points, and "input seeking" is faster. There are cases in which we can't use the -ss before the -i and have to use it after. I saw lots of discussions about the subject...

@Rotem "There are cases in which we can't use the -ss before the -i and have to use it after." - Does this apply not only to trimming without re-encoding, but also to trimming with re-encoding?
